# CUDA half float operations without explicit intrinsics

Tags: cuda, intrinsics, nvcc, fma, half-precision-float

I am using CUDA 11.2 and I use the `__half` type to do operations on 16 bit floating point values.

I am surprised that the nvcc compiler will not properly invoke fused multiply add instructions when I do:

```
__half a,b,c;
...
__half x = a * b + c;
```

Instead of emitting a fused multiply add, it emits separate mul and add instructions.

```
mul.f16 %rs164,%rs1,%rs306;
add.f16 %rs167,%rs164,%rs65;
```

Note that this is despite using the `--fmad=true` compiler option.

Whereas an explicit `__hfma( a,b,c )` will emit:

```
fma.rn.f16 %rs164,%rs1,%rs300,%rs65;
```

Is the only way to utilize 16 bit floating point multiply-add to use explicit intrinsics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The instructions that are actually executed by the GPU are SASS, not PTX.  PTX is an intermediate format, and the tool that converts PTX to SASS is an *optimizing* compiler.

When I perform an operation as you suggest, and study the SASS, I witness a fused-multiply-add instruction being generated:

```
$ cat t111.cu
#include <cuda_fp16.h>
__global__ void k(__half *x, __half a, __half b, __half c){
        *x = a*b+c;
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_75 -c t111.cu
$ cuobjdump -ptx t111.o

Fatbin elf code:
================
arch = sm_75
code version = [1,7]
producer = <unknown>
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit

Fatbin ptx code:
================
arch = sm_75
code version = [7,1]
producer = <unknown>
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit
compressed

.version 7.1
.target sm_75
.address_size 64



.visible .entry _Z1kP6__halfS_S_S_(
.param .u64 _Z1kP6__halfS_S_S__param_0,
.param .align 2 .b8 _Z1kP6__halfS_S_S__param_1[2],
.param .align 2 .b8 _Z1kP6__halfS_S_S__param_2[2],
.param .align 2 .b8 _Z1kP6__halfS_S_S__param_3[2]
)
{
.reg .b16 %rs<7>;
.reg .b64 %rd<3>;


ld.param.u64 %rd1, [_Z1kP6__halfS_S_S__param_0];
ld.param.u16 %rs2, [_Z1kP6__halfS_S_S__param_1];
ld.param.u16 %rs3, [_Z1kP6__halfS_S_S__param_2];
ld.param.u16 %rs6, [_Z1kP6__halfS_S_S__param_3];
cvta.to.global.u64 %rd2, %rd1;

        {mul.f16 %rs1,%rs2,%rs3;
}


        {add.f16 %rs4,%rs1,%rs6;
}

        st.global.u16 [%rd2], %rs4;
ret;
}


$ cuobjdump -sass t111.o

Fatbin elf code:
================
arch = sm_75
code version = [1,7]
producer = <unknown>
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit

        code for sm_75
                Function : _Z1kP6__halfS_S_S_
        .headerflags    @"EF_CUDA_SM75 EF_CUDA_PTX_SM(EF_CUDA_SM75)"
        /*0000*/                   MOV R1, c[0x0][0x28] ;                                /* 0x00000a0000017a02 */
                                                                                         /* 0x000fd00000000f00 */
        /*0010*/                   LDC.U16 R0, c[0x0][0x168] ;                           /* 0x00005a00ff007b82 */
                                                                                         /* 0x000e220000000400 */
        /*0020*/                   ULDC.64 UR4, c[0x0][0x160] ;                          /* 0x0000580000047ab9 */
                                                                                         /* 0x000fce0000000a00 */
        /*0030*/                   LDC.U16 R3, c[0x0][0x16a] ;                           /* 0x00005a80ff037b82 */
                                                                                         /* 0x000e240000000400 */
        /*0040*/                   HFMA2 R0, R0.H0_H0, R3.H0_H0, c[0x0] [0x16c].H0_H0 ;  /* 0x20005b0000007631 */
                                                                                         /* 0x001fd00000040803 */
        /*0050*/                   STG.E.U16.SYS [UR4], R0 ;                             /* 0x00000000ff007986 */
                                                                                         /* 0x000fe2000c10e504 */
        /*0060*/                   EXIT ;                                                /* 0x000000000000794d */
                                                                                         /* 0x000fea0003800000 */
        /*0070*/                   BRA 0x70;                                             /* 0xfffffff000007947 */
                                                                                         /* 0x000fc0000383ffff */
                ..........



Fatbin ptx code:
================
arch = sm_75
code version = [7,1]
producer = <unknown>
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit
compressed
$
```

(CUDA 11.1)

I don't recommend PTX analysis to answer questions like this.